# Указать тип колонки View

Tags: sql-server, view

Имеется табличное выражение на основе которого будет создан View

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT N'Нет' AS C1 FROM tbl ) SELECT CTE.C1 FROM CTE;
```

Табличное выражение достаточно объемное. Не хотелось бы загромождать его подобными кусками:

```
CAST(CTE.C1 AS NVARCHAR(3)) AS C1
```

**Вопрос**: Как указать тип данных в колонках View и обязательно ли это делать (по аналогии с таблицей) если фактические значения всегда входят в предполагаемый диапазон (Инструкция CASE...ELSE)?

Comment: Если хотите указываейте, а так тип данных унаследуется от типов в таблице.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov я прежде всего имею ввиду вычисляемые колонки в которых выводятся константы как в примере `N'Нет'`

Comment: Лучше указать там, где возвращаются константы, иначе рано или поздно вместо "да", "нет", "другое" получите "да", "не", "др"

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Можете оформить свой комментарий как ответ с примером из 1-2 колонок? В итоге в выборке из табличного выражения лучше не приводить константы к конкретному типу?